# Use <th> Tag for HeaderTemplate in ASP DataList

Tags: asp.net, datalist

Is it possible to let the DataList control use a `<th>` tag for the header template instead of a regular `<td>` cell? Using a repeater control isn't a solution since I need a multi-column layout.

Comment: Repeaters can do multi-column fine. I use repeaters to build tables to apply [jQuery Datatable](http://www.datatables.net/) to them.

Comment: can you specify what data do you want to display and why do you want `<th>` instead of `<td>`

Comment: It's a pretty simple scenario: I want to render a custom control per container item in a two column table layout. The head needs to be a <th> tag since the result should look the same - I'm replacing a static html.